# Overriding NSDate property in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an Objective-C class `MyClass` that I'm subclassing in Swift. I'm trying to override the `lastModifiedDateTime` property which is an `NSDate`. When I try to compile the below code I get an error `Cannot override mutable property lastModifiedDateTime of type NSDate! with covariant type NSDate`

Is there a way to fix this error?

```
class MySubclass : MyClass {

    var date = NSDate()

    override var lastModifiedDateTime: NSDate {
        return date
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `NSDate!` as your `override var` type?

Comment: as @Ian said, I think it's an optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the superclass' property is a pointer, you need to make the subclass' property either an optional (`NSDate?`) or an implicitly-unwrapped optional (`NSDate!`), plus add `get`/`set` as appropriate to match the superclass' access.

```
class MySubclass: MyClass {

    var date = NSDate()

    override var myDate: NSDate! {
        get {
            return date;
        }
        set {
            date = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it fixed my specific compile error. I forgot to mention that the property is @dynamic so I had to override the actual getter function as well.